# ASIhttprequest convert response to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am sending request to the server in my app and the server return a response 
Example:

```
ASIhttprequest *request;.......-> sending request.......
```

Reciving Request.........->
    NSlog(@"%@",[request response]);

the request return like this :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
<div>

</div>
</form>
```

any idea what can i do from here to convert this response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an `NSString` from ASI you need to use the `responseString` property, rather than just `response`. For example:

`NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);`